# Using Windows Authentication in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, authentication

I'm working on a Rails app for an internal project and can't work out how to set up the users model to use Windows Authentication for logging in. I had a look and can't find anything that was covering this topic. I've managed to configure Rails to use SQLServer fine but I'm just blanking here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No idea if this helps — http://www.zorched.net/2007/06/04/active-directory-authentication-for-ruby-on-rails/ .

Comment: It certainly looks useful. I'd looked at it previously but missed the Apache info. Thanks (if you submit it as an answer I can mark it as accepted)